# How to design a gradient background of a page with unfixed height

Tags: html, css

How to design

1) a vertical gradient background with unfixed height,

2) a vertical gradient background with fixed height (say 600px, from blue to white to green), then the rest has the same green color?

---

***update***

Now the new design is from the top to the bottom, 120px fixed height from blue to white, then unfixed height for white, and then 120px fixed height from white to green. How to code that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do it, you will want to take advantage of the available background properties:

```
body {
    background-color: green;
    background-image: linear-gradient(blue, white, green);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 600px;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/sl1dr/PxNhY/

If you want an unfixed height then replace 600px with 100%.

EDIT: Here is the new solution according to your changes: http://jsfiddle.net/sl1dr/EtYLZ/

Comment: The new method doesn't work for scrolling, it adjusts to the window size, instead of the `body`.

Comment: It works fine for scrolling, if you want proof then swap body { height: 100%; } for body { height: 2000px; }

Comment: Yes, I had that in there for the example due to the lack of content. This won't be an issue on your site as you have content!

Comment: But when there is not enough content, I still want the height of the body/html to be the height of the window, how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can try crossbrowser (ie5.5+) linerar [gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Answer (score -1):

This Link:
[Css Gradient From Green To White To Blue](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#3669d1+0,ffffff+51,9ecb2d+100;Custom)

Or you can use this link directly: [Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor) for generating cross-browser Css 3.0 Backgrounds.
You can generate Professional gradients and get the code for pasting in your own css file.
You must know that the css may not support some versions of IE