# Eliminate extra height in HTML

Tags: html, css

There are a few similar questions in SO but not exact, and none of them can solve my problem.

I have the following structure of a html page

> ```
> <html><body>
>     <div class="container" style="height:auto;">
>       <div class="header" style="height:120px;">...</div>
>       <div class="context" style="height:360px;">
>         <div id="area1" style="height:440px; position:relative; top:-20px;"></div>
>         <div id="area2" style="height:120px; position:relative; top:-140px;"></div>
>       </div>
>       <div class="footer" style="height:120px;">...</div>
>     </div>
> </body></html>
> ```

Basically, there is a div with height 440px in `context` whose height is 360px. So the div will overlap with both `header` and `footer` for 20px and 60px, respectively.

The height of the `container` is set to auto, and it shows "600px" using "inspect element", so is `body`. But `html` has a height of 680px.

I know where the extra 80px comes from, but how to eliminate that?

I have another question but it seems no one would answer it after I updated a further question. [How to design a gradient background of a page with unfixed height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222082/how-to-design-a-gradient-background-of-a-page-with-unfixed-height/8224437#8224437). If that problem can be solved, maybe I can avoid this problem.

*** update ***

It seems I simply the code too much, there are actually two `div` in `context`, `area1` and `area2`. `area2` of height 120px overlaps with `area1` completely.

Comment: isn't html height == browser window height?

Comment: My HTML is 616px in height if I use your code. I'm not sure where those extra pixels come from, though it might some kind of unrendered gutter.

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato why html height is not equal to container height?

Comment: I figured out. I replace `position:relative; top:-20px;` with `margin-top:-20px`, and similar to the other one, then it is perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. I replace `position:relative; top:-20px;` with `margin-top:-20px`, and similar to the other one, then it is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Do you realize the CSS is incorrect?

You need semicolons between these properties:

```
 style="height:440px position:relative top:-20px"
```

Like this:

```
 style="height:440px; position:relative; top:-20px"
```